# How to get FlexBox elements to overlap an SVG element?

Tags: css, svg, z-index

I need to overlap an SVG element's top and bottom with FlexBox items so that the space between them is gone.

What I've tried:

- Added a z-index of 1 to the FlexBox items but that didn't do anything.
- Added a z-index of -1 to the SVG element but that only hid the element entirely, which is not what I wanted.

Here's my code:

```
// Lottie returns an SVG with class wrapper.

const defaultOptions = {                                                                      
        loop: false,    
        autoplay: true,                                                                               
        animationData: balanceData.default,                                                           
        rendererSettings: {                                                                          
                preserveAspectRatio: 'xMidYMid slice',                                                
                className: 'wrapper'                                                
        }               
};
```

---

```
// home.js

<div className="message"> 
        <div className="txt-1">Find                
        </div>                 

        <Lottie options={defaultOptions}                                              
                height={510}                                                                  
                width={310}                                                                   
        />         

        <div className="txt-2">with your</div>                 
        <div className="txt-3">body & mind.</div>
```

```
// home.css

.message {
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        font-size: 6em;
        align-items: center;
        display: flex;
        padding-left: 60px;
        padding-top: 60px;
        flex-direction: column;
}

.txt-1 {
        opacity: 0;
        animation-name: txt-1;
        animation-duration: 2s;
        animation-delay: .5s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
        z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes txt-1 {
        0% {
                opacity: 0;
        }
        100% {
                opacity: 1;
        }
}

.txt-2 {
        opacity: 0;
        animation-name: txt-2;
        animation-duration: 1.5s;
        animation-delay: 1s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes txt-2 {
        0% {
                opacity: 0;
        }
        100% {
                opacity: 1;
        }
}

.txt-3 {
        opacity: 0;
        animation-name: txt-3;
        animation-duration: 2s;
        animation-delay: 1.5s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes txt-3 {
        0% {
                opacity: 0;
        }
        100% {
                opacity: 1;
        }
}
```

Again, all I want is for space between the FlexBox items and SVG element to be hidden:

[image]

Comment: Only god could understand what you mean

Comment: @CuongHoang lmao damn where did I lose you help a sista out

Comment: wait, i am writing code on jsfiddle

Comment: Your SVG is a flex item. You would need to take it out of the `.message` div before trying anything.

Comment: change the SVG, cut off the space

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Just had to remove `align-items: center;` from `.message` and add the following to `.wrapper`:

```
.wrapper {
   padding-left: 5%;
   width: 90% !important;
   display: flex !important;
}
```

to make my UI look like:

[image]

**Note:** I'm well aware it's highly suggested to only use `!important` in either utility cases or user stylesheets. But the library I'm using to render my SVG doesn't allow me to change their stylesheet, so I feel this is a justified use-case of it.